# OpenSSL generate certificate

Tags: wordpress, openssl

i'm faceing some issue with an ssl certificate that i need for payment gateway,i already generated it but it doesn't work,i'm already doing a 3d payment gateway with a plugin that requires that certification..

I opened ssl via command prompt generated it but still i get the error request that the certification is invalid,is it possible that i did something wrong here is how it is required

> > OpenSSL Setup Prior to proceeding, it is necessary to download Win32 OpenSSL which can be found at: https://www.openssl.org/source/ After
> > the software is set up, it is important to enter a variable Path for a
> > bin catalogue.
>
> 1. In system variables: Variable PATH → “Change” Put a semicolon at the end of the line and enter a pathway to the bin folder:
>    c:\OpenSSL\bin For the next step, in the console, open the batch
>    folder and run run.bat (one of the attachments in the email received
>    from UPC)
> 2. The command can be performed for example in FAR. For this, place the cursor on run.bat file,  press Ctrl Enter and add MERCHANT ID with
>    a space Key Generation Key generation and exchange is performed after
>    the Merchant sends a request for registration and receives  E-shop
>    attributes via Internet (that includes a Merchant ID) Prior to key
>    generation, it is necessary to edit the file config.dat according to
>    the data of the E-shop.  Config.dat data shall not strictly correspond
>    with the data in the request; such data is used for neither signature
>    generation nor signature verification and is only used for an
>    identification of a certificate file.

Can someone please explain me a little how to do it in steps i already watched some tutorials on youtube but i think i did something wrong,ill hope someone here can tell me how to fix this issue thank you very much